# Routing with mixed ASP.NET Webform and MVC environment

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, webforms

I have an existing ASP.NET webforms website and I have two pages that are ASP.NET MVC that I want to have coexist on the same site.

It works fine except for default documents -- I want htp://localhost to show localhost/default.aspx. Currently:

- htp://localhost/ displays the MVC page which should be: htp://localhost/TestPage/Index
- htp://localhost/default.aspx displays the webforms page (as it should)

There's nothing special in the RouteConfig.cs -- I'm just using this:

```
routes.MapRoute(name: "MVCPage", 
url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
defaults: new { controller = "TestPage", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an ignore route statement.

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("default.aspx");
```

https://weblogs.asp.net/pjohnson/mvc-s-ignoreroute-syntax
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/f82e9a/ignore-route-in-mvc/
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505203(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: it's close, but now I get a 404 at htp://localhost/ (but not at htp://localhost/default.aspx)

Comment: @AmandaH: Your particular case may need tweaking, that's why I provided the articles. This is the method to do what you want to do, but getting it to work exactly may take extra modification.